# How to pass event parameter to aws lambda function via EventBridge when there is field updated in mongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I'm wanted to trigger lambda function when a specific field in mongoDB collection is update but the lambda fucntion needed some parameters. How to send some parameter to eventBridge?

How to pass event parameter to aws lambda function via EventBridge when there is field updated in mongoDB collection?